# How to replace value in list at same collection location

Tags: c#

How do I replace a value in a collection list at the same location?

```
0 = cat
1 = dog
2 = bird
```

replace `2` with `snail`?

Comment: what is your collection type?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
yourCollection[2] = "Snail";
```

Comment: How did I manage not to think of that?

Answer (score 84):

In a bigger `List<T>` collection, you would like to find index to replace...with:

```
 var i = animals.FindIndex(x => x == "Dog");
 animals[i] = "Snail";
```

Comment: FindIndex isn't Linq, it's a method on List<T> so it's not available for other collection types

Comment: ok, i removed the word LINQ, since it isnt part of it.

Comment: Use the function 'Equals' for string compare.

Comment: var i = animals.FindIndex(x=> string.Compare(x, "Dog").Equals(0))

Comment: Honest question: Why using the method Equals to compare strings? The == operator always worked fine for me.

Comment: @RicardoPieper == operator compares references, not string values. That being said, bool compare  = "test" ==  "test"; will result in false

Comment: @Greensy are you sure you're not thinking about Java now? :)

Comment: @Greensy C# isn't a complete copy/paste of Java :D I'm pretty sure that code yields true, since i've been using the == operator since forever, and it never fails me.

Also, I looked at the reference source for the == operator. Equals and == basically do the same thing, but you can do some tweaking with Equals... which is rarely the case for me.

Comment: In fact, the == operator just calls the static method string.Equals(string str). 

So yeah, `==` all the way.

Answer (score -21):

```
List<string> animals = new List<string>();
animals.Add("cat");
animals.Add("dog");
animals.Add("bird");
animals.Add("fish");

animals.RemoveAt(2);
animals.Insert(2, "snail");
```

Comment: Not very efficient for larger collections. Why not just `animals[2] = "snail";` instead?

Comment: Not all paths are of equal length.

Comment: Works for me! @LukeH in my project example `list[index] = value` not worked.

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.